# How can I remove aluminum foil from a candy cane?

Tags: candy, aluminum-foil

I got a rather large candy cane, and was far from able to finish it in a single sitting. I thought I would preserve it by wrapping it (somewhat tightly) in aluminum foil. Now, a month later, I can't get it off. I have tried everything up to scraping it with a butter knife, but I can't get all of the foil off. Any advice? I would rather not throw the whole thing away.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a wet, lint-free towel for a few minutes - this will dissolve the sugar near the surface and you should be able to peel the foil off.  Repeat as necessary.